# How to check if the http request to an IIS corresponds to a sharepoint site request

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, iis, sharepoint-2010

I have a HTTPModule code which provides me the current user logged in and few other information as soon as a request is made to the IIS. We are performing some tasks based on this information.

But this is getting triggered each and every time any request is made (Which it should). Problem here is that I have other sites also hosted on this IIS and these sites needs to be filtered out from the above processing. This filtering is not happening as a result of which the above code is getting fired for all the sites, which I want to restrict only to sharepoint related sites.

How could I know whether the http request is for a sharepoint site or any general site?

Any help or pointer in this regards will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you implemented a module at IIS level.

You should be doing it at the application level, the one that is serving your sharepoint sites.

You can do this by implementing a solution with a webapplication feature that will modify the web.config of the Sharepoint application(s). You can do this by using the SPWebConfigModification API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861909(v=office.14).aspx

At IIS level you will need to analyse the request and do some filtering based on URL or other parameters, which will be problematic on the long run as it will require constant adjustment.

Comment: I can not do it at application level. Whenever a new site is created in a new webApp in sharepoint, a new website gets hosted on IIS. An Admin can create n number of webapp and/or sites in sharepoint. It will be a big pain to alter each and every web.config which was previously created and which will be further getting created. So I need to implement it at IIS level.

Also as you said, I just need the filter criteria based on which I could decide if the request is for a sharepoint site.

Comment: It wont be a pain if you implement that as a Sharepoint application feature. You can even set a flag enable by default that will enable it automatically in new Webapplications. Bear in mind that the method above handles all changes for you. You dont have to worry about editing web.config files manually